# How can I generate a self-signed certificate with a hash other than SHA-1 on cisco ASA?

Tags: cisco-asa

I have a Cisco ASA 5508-X with IOS 9.6(1), and I have Apex licenses for AnyConnect which support Suite B, NGE. How can I generate a self-signed certificate with a hash other than default SHA-1. For example SHA256 or SHA512? I dont see those settings under trustpoint?

Comment: "_ASA supports the SHA-2 signature algorithm starting from 8.2(5) [pre-8.3 releases] and 8.4(1) [post-8.3 releases] onwards (Cisco bug ID [CSCti30937](https://bst.cloudapps.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCti30937))._"

Comment: But I dont see command under Trustpoint to configure hash?

Comment: If you care enough about security to want to use Suite B, do you really want to use a self-signed certificate?

Comment: ASAs do support SHA-256 certs but you can’t generate them on-device - you have to generate them on a separate system and then import them to the ASA.